# Can't access squid proxy from remote machine

Tags: proxy, squid

I have set up a squid proxy on a Ubuntu machine, and I'd like to do some testing by accessing the proxy from another computer (NOT on the same lan). But I seem to be unable to connect to the squid proxy server.

I've tried several different ways to connect: by setting the proxy in my web browser, and by using the unix program "curl" to issue http requests from a command line. But I just can't connect.

I've tried setting the acl in the configuration file squid.conf to allow access from the remote machine. So I don't know what's going on. If I try to access the internet from the same machine that the squid proxy is on, it works correctly.

The lines in squid.conf that I added to allow access from the remote machine are:

```
acl my_machine src 50.193.61.125/255.255.255.0
http_access allow my_machine
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done to allow the remote machine to access the squid proxy?

Thanks.

Comment: Might have better luck here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Whats your network layout like? Is this machine on the edge of your network?

Comment: The squid server is on a virtual machine hosted by Amazon. I'm trying to access the server from an actual computer.

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem. ec2 instance with fedora 19 os and squid 3.2.9. also created a security group incoming rule for port 3128. wont work if i connect from a remote pc. think there is a restriction in the aws-cloud.